# How to get good plots in Spyder python ? (Inline and Qt5)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, qt5, inline

When i plot in Spyder with the Backend Qt5 in graphics ( the window that pops with the plot) i don't get things aesthetically beautiful. The title sometimes is not showing, the labels, ... All in all it is just not good looking. But when it is plotted "inline" it is very well presented.

What I want is :
I want the plot with the Backend Qt5 option very well presented like the Backend Inline option.

The code is this :

```
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,2, num = 5))
    plt.title('Blabla')
    plt.xlabel('Anything')
    plt.ylabel('Everything')
```

[What I get with the Backend Qt5 option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LheGl.png)
[What I get with the Backend Inline option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwHGz.png)

Comment: maybe a [`plt.tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html) could help…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the use of this line in order to increase the quality of the plots:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
```

In Qt5 it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command `%matplotlib qt` might be the solution to this problem. You should write the line in the IPython Console.

Comment: It doesnt give me what I want. the command you shared all it does is display the plot in a pop-up window which I already know hwo to do it. The question is how to plot with the Qt5 and everything is visible title, labels, etc. Look at the pictures shared it explains it